# NoReverseMatch at /checkout/ - Django Website

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

**django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'update_cart' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart\/(?P[^/]+)$']
[18/Apr/2020 14:05:02] "GET /checkout/ HTTP/1.1" 500 157543** <--- this is the error message I am getting in terminal when I try to go onto the checkout page.

view.html

```
{% for item in cart.products.all %}

<tr><td> {{ item }} </td><td>{{item.price}}</td>

<td><a href='{% url "update_cart" item.slug %}'> Remove</a></td></tr>
{% endfor %}

</table>

<br/>

<a href='{% url "checkout" %}'>Checkout</a>

{% endif %}
</div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

views.py for orders

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect

# Create your views here.

from carts.models import Cart

def checkout(request):
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)

    except:
        the_id = None
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("fuisce-home"))


    context = {}
    template = "fuisce/home.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from carts import views as cart_views
from orders import views as order_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('cart/', cart_views.view, name='cart'),
    path('cart/<slug>', cart_views.update_cart, name='update_cart'),
    path('checkout/', order_views.checkout, name='checkout'),
]
```

I can't figure out where the problem is occurring, as was working perfectly until a few minutes ago. Any solutions would be greatly appreciated!

**update** -- the problem seems to arise when i move the HttpResponse from just below def checkout, to below cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id). (change in code attached below). anyone know how to let it accept this change?

```
def checkout(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("fuisce-home"))
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
except:
            the_id = None

def checkout(request):
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)

    except:
        the_id = None
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("fuisce-home"))
```

Comment: My guess is that `item.slug` is missing or blank.  Try printing it in the template.

Comment: @JohnGordon thanks for the reply, its printed in the template as so: <td><a href='{% url "update_cart" item.slug %}'> Remove</a></td></tr>
{% endfor %}

</table>

Answer (score 1):

Slug field is missing in view.html for checkout url

Comment: thanks for the reply! adding in an item.slug for checkout url didn't fix the error unfortunately.